# No orange start page in localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Apache friends

I've installed xampp-win32-5.6.11-0-VC11 and in XAMPP control panel I can start Apache and MySQL. They start without any errors.

But... when I type localhost in my browser I am redirected to another page http://localhost/dashboard/ 
I don't have that orange start page as shown in all the manuals/tutorials. I mean, I don't have this page.

If I type localhost/xampp/index.php manually, I get into Google in Chrome or if I use Mozilla, I get this error:
“Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 “

I also don't have splash.php file for some reasons...

Could anyone can help to run he localhot orange proper.

Answer (score 1):

The old orange XAMPP administration page is no longer included in current XAMPP versions. The Object cannot be found because it does not exist. The localhost/dashboard is the new default start page. If you want the old orange start page you will need to go back to the older version.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11607415)

Comment: Thankyou. I updated and removed the links. I suppose the pertinent information is that it simply no longer exists.

Comment: I think it answers perfectly. The question: 'Could anyone can help to run he localhost orange proper.' No. No one can help the questioner get to the orange page because it no longer exists in new versions. I struggled for weeks to find an answer to why I could not get to the orange page. Once I figured out it no longer existed, I could seek ways to do the development differently.